# Move 2 objects with constraints in AFRAME

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, keyboard-events, aframe

I am having 2 objects and I want them to have movement as shown here:

[image: GOAL]

Now I have their 3D models as **stl** & their offset calculations.

I can also import them into aframe, but after that unable to figure out their movements using keyboard press. and maintain their posture  e.g.

1. I want **square** element to move linearly by specific length **when Q is Pressed**
2. **Round** Element Rotary movement by specific degrees **when R is pressed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

**1) React on keypress:**

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 118) {

   }
};
```

You can react on either `charCode` (ASCII) or `key`('d', 'f'..). 
Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/86h3kop0/6/).

**2) Rotation and movement within "boundaries"**

if you want the square to move along a cylinder, make it a **child** of the cylinder.

```
<a-cylinder>
  <a-box></a-box>
<a-cylinder>
```

now, the box will move within the parents frame of reference. Moving it "forward" won't move it along the *world* "forward" vector, but along the *parent* "forward" vector.

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7e4y3mtr/6/).

Comment: Thanks Piotr Adam Milewski, 
You have used **animation API of aframe**, but i intended to use **keypresses** in order to initiate **movement**. I think this is possible via **queryselector** . I know how the events are being used, as you have mentioned above , but i am mainly confused what to write inside of them. Can you do this in the fiddle ?

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7e4y3mtr/13/), **q** moves one entity, **e** moves the other